# Header not functioning properly Firefox / Internet explorer

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a header for a website. I am using a template for the menu; however it has started to malfunction in IE9 and FireFox, yet works perfectly in webkit browsers.

In IE9 the rings tab doesnt drop down; in FireFox it gets cut off.

I have a feeling I may have changed 1 or 2 attributes that created this error, but I cannot locate them. Any ideas?

[Here is a link to the website.](http://morzi.com/hfe/)

Comment: I just corrected your link which was formatted as a code block.

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever heard of the Developer Tools? Hit F12.

> HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. The shortest valid doctype is "`<!DOCTYPE html>`".
>   hfe, line 1 character 1
>
> HTML1511: Unexpected head-level element encountered outside of "`<head>`".
>   hfe, line 5 character 3
>
> HTML1511: Unexpected head-level element encountered outside of "`<head>`".
>   hfe, line 7 character 2
>
> HTML1511: Unexpected head-level element encountered outside of "`<head>`".
>   hfe, line 8 character 2
>
> HTML1511: Unexpected head-level element encountered outside of "`<head>`".
>   hfe, line 9 character 2

The main problem is that you have a `</head>` tag on line 4 and a `<body>` tag on line 22, neither of which should be there. You're also missing a DOCTYPE, which is causing the browser to be in Quirks Mode. This is probably also causing the cut-off menus in Firefox (and IE when told to force Standards mode)

Comment: Yeah, the HTML is a disaster here. You even have code after the closing body tag, and then another closing body tag. Egads.

Comment: I was trying to use php to include the header, which i made using a body tag. i fixed the html but the issues still remain. any help?